# Change placement of multi-column header

Tags: tables, booktabs

Right now I have the following table:

[image]

Which corresponds to this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp] 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c } 
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Portfolio size} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){3-5} 
Sub-period & Cum. return (\%) & Min & Median & Max \\ 
\midrule 
a) 2004-2007 & & & & \\
\midrule
FDR ($1\%$) & 25.711 & 0 & 1 & 8 \\ 
FDR ($10\%$) & 3.907 & 4 & 8 & 34\\ 
FDR ($20\%$) & 3.041 & 1 & 13 & 21\\ 
Best $20$ keywords & 4.847 & 20 & 20 & 20\\ 
Best keyword & -0.945 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
Buy \& Hold & 22.176 & - & - & -\\ 
\midrule 
b) 2008-2012 & & & & \\
\midrule
FDR ($1\%$) & 28.226 & 2 & 6 & 24 \\ 
FDR ($10\%$) & 8.258 & 6 & 23 & 49\\ 
FDR ($20\%$) & 18.323 & 0 & 32 & 67\\ 
Best $20$ keywords & 19.154 & 20 & 20 & 20\\ 
Best keyword & 41.768 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
Buy \& Hold & 5.929 & - & - & -\\ 
\midrule 
c) 2013-2017 & & & & \\
\midrule
FDR ($1\%$) & 17.023 & 0 & 3 & 5 \\ 
FDR ($10\%$) & 13.732 & 5 & 10 & 43\\ 
FDR ($20\%$) & 4.782 & 10 & 18 & 69\\ 
Best $20$ keywords & 2.074 & 20 & 20 & 20\\ 
Best keyword & 13.121 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
Buy \& Hold & 82.153 & - & - & -\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Persistence tests, ignoring transaction costs.}
\label{tab:persT} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I would like the multicolumn description 'Portfolio size' to be in the middle of the midrule, i.e. somewhere above 'Median'.

Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like the multicolumn description 'Portfolio size' to be in the middle of the midrule, i.e., somewhere above 'Median'.

Just change

```
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Portfolio size} \\
```

to

```
&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Portfolio size} \\
```

Notice that there are two changes: (a) there's an extra `&` symbol and (b) the first argument of `\multicolumn` has changed from `4` to `3`. These two changes work together: Initially, the string "Portfolio size" is centered over **4** columns (columns 2 thru 5); after the change, it is centered over **3** columns (columns 3 thru 5).

---

In addition to fixing the position of the header string, you should consider making the numbers easier to read by aligning them on their (explicit or implicit) decimal markers. This may be achieved by loading the `siunitx` package and using the `S` column type.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp] 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=2.3] *{3}{S[table-format=2.0]} @{}} 
\toprule 
Subperiod & {Cum.\ return (\%)} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Portfolio size} \\     
\cmidrule(l){3-5} 
 && {Min} & {Median} & {Max} \\ 
\midrule 
a) 2004--2007 & & & & \\
\addlinespace % less obtrusive than '\midrule'
FDR (1\%) & 25.711 & 0 & 1 & 8 \\ 
FDR (10\%) & 3.907 & 4 & 8 & 34\\ 
FDR (20\%) & 3.041 & 1 & 13 & 21\\ 
Best 20 keywords & 4.847 & 20 & 20 & 20\\ 
Best keyword & -0.945 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
Buy \& Hold & 22.176 & {--} & {--} & {--} \\  
\midrule 
b) 2008--2012 & & & & \\
\addlinespace
FDR (1\%) & 28.226 & 2 & 6 & 24 \\ 
FDR (10\%) & 8.258 & 6 & 23 & 49\\ 
FDR (20\%) & 18.323 & 0 & 32 & 67\\ 
Best 20 keywords & 19.154 & 20 & 20 & 20\\ 
Best keyword & 41.768 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
Buy \& Hold & 5.929 & {--} & {--} & {--} \\  
\midrule 
c) 2013--2017 & & & & \\
\addlinespace
FDR (1\%) & 17.023 & 0 & 3 & 5 \\ 
FDR (10\%) & 13.732 & 5 & 10 & 43\\ 
FDR (20\%) & 4.782 & 10 & 18 & 69\\ 
Best 20 keywords & 2.074 & 20 & 20 & 20\\ 
Best keyword & 13.121 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
Buy \& Hold & 82.153 & {--} & {--} & {--} \\  
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Persistence tests, ignoring transaction costs.}
\label{tab:persT} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! What exactly does adding an extra '&' do?

Comment: @John - Please see the additional explanation I posted in the body of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I propose some improvements. I don't think it's necessary to use the `S` column type for the last three columns, and  I prefer  to have less horizontal rules, replacing the rules after the years with a boldface font:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{l S c c c }
\toprule
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Portfolio size} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-5}
Sub-period & {Cum. return (\%)} & Min & Median & Max \\
\midrule
\textbf{a) 2004–2007} & & & & \\
\addlinespace[0.5ex]
FDR ($1\,\%$) & 25.711 & 0 & 1 & 8 \\
FDR ($10\,\%$) & 3.907 & 4 & 8 & 34\\
FDR ($20\,\%$) & 3.041 & 1 & 13 & 21\\
Best $20$ keywords & 4.847 & 20 & 20 & 20\\
Best keyword & -0.945 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
Buy \& Hold & 22.176 & – & – & – \\
\midrule
\textbf{b) 2008–2012} & & & & \\%
\addlinespace[0.5ex]
FDR ($1\,\%$) & 28.226 & 2 & 6 & 24 \\
FDR ($10\,\%$) & 8.258 & 6 & 23 & 49\\
FDR ($20\,\%$) & 18.323 & 0 & 32 & 67\\
Best $20$ keywords & 19.154 & 20 & 20 & 20\\
Best keyword & 41.768 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
Buy \& Hold & 5.929 & – & – & – \\
\midrule
\textbf{c) 2013–2017} & & & & \\%
\addlinespace[0.5ex]
FDR ($1\,\%$) & 17.023 & 0 & 3 & 5 \\
FDR ($10\,\%$) & 13.732 & 5 & 10 & 43\\
FDR ($20\,\%$) & 4.782 & 10 & 18 & 69\\
Best $20$ keywords & 2.074 & 20 & 20 & 20\\
Best keyword & 13.121 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
Buy \& Hold & 82.153 & – & – & – \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Persistence tests, ignoring transaction costs.}
\label{tab:persT}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! yes. I forgot those ones. I'll fix that. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: I couldn't see where he struck, mylord, but just in case I made a new copy of the code, hopefully circumventing the gremlin. Is it OK now?

Comment: But I usually type em- and en-dashes on my keyboard,  save them as such, and have no problem compiling.